# SQL-Server Datetime in WHERE Clause Issue

Tags: sql-server, datetime, where-clause

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SP7Re.png)I am creating a query of two values, a period number and the corresponding date. The periods are accounting periods that are similar but not identical to our months. The dates are largely correct, but there are a few inconsistencies that I thought I would clean up with a WHERE statement.

For example, the date 4/1/2015 belongs in period 3, but it shows up in both period 3 and period 4. To fix this, I thought that I would create a WHERE statement stating:

```
SELECT DISTINCT table1.period,
                table1.datetime
FROM table1
WHERE table1.period <> 4 AND table1.datetime <> '4/1/2015'
```

This took away all of period 4 away instead of just the one I needed. I have also tried the datetime syntax:

```
AND table1.datetime <> '20150401 00:00:00.000'
```

Both syntaxes had the same results. I am fairly inexperienced at SQL and have always hated dealing with datetime values, so any help would be great.

-EDIT- Forgot to add single quotations to the first datetime WHERE clause.

Comment: which is the type of  table1.datetime?

Comment: @alex it is a datetime data type, and period is a string.

Comment: Does it have a time value for the date? You may need to cast as date when comparing to a date string. As in '4/1/2015 01:00:00.000' does not equal '4/1/2015' but CAST('4/1/2015 01:00:00.000' AS DATE) does.

Comment: Notice you also are missing the dashes in your string literal? '2015-04-01' My guess is the date issue is not the actual problem. If there is time in the value this will not work either.

Comment: Perhaps if you provided the ddl and some sample data it would quickly become obvious what the problem is. As it is we are left guessing.

Comment: @BinaryPatrick there are time values, but they are all 00:00.000 values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT table1.period,
            table1.datetime
FROM table1
WHERE CASE WHEN table1.period = 4 AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),table1.datetime,112) = '20150401' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END = 0
```

This only get rid of rows that both has `period=4` and `datetime=20150401`, while your query first get rid of anything that has `period=4`(no matter what [datetime] is), then get rid of anything has `datetime=20150401`.

Comment: Case statements only change the output when your using an OR. Statements that AND conditions are evaluated the same. Having them both with an AND statement means they both have to be true to remain in the set

Answer (score 0):

Did you say that period is a string field ? you mean a varchar ?
Also you want to check on the date part only, not the time ?

then you can try this

```
SELECT DISTINCT table1.period,
                table1.datetime
FROM table1
WHERE table1.period <> '4' 
AND convert(date, table1.datetime) <> '20150401'
```

Comment: This works in getting rid of the Period 4 (4/1/2015) while keeping all other Period 4 dates, but also gets rid of Period 3 (4/1/2015) which is the correct date.